# Implement Twitter timeline partway through View Controller?

Tags: swift, xcode, twitter

I'm using Twitter Kit and am trying to implement the timeline partway through the main View Controller like so.

[Twitter Timeline plus Scroll View 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ4Fp.png)

[Twitter Timeline plus Scrol View 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVTTg.png)

Essentially have a scroll view and underneath that the Twitter timeline. 
I have the code for the timeline as a separate view, but I'm having trouble implementing it alongside another class.

```
let client = TWTRAPIClient()
    self.dataSource = TWTRListTimelineDataSource(listSlug: "surfing", listOwnerScreenName: "stevenhepting", apiClient: client)
```

Edit from comments: I tried implementing the Twitter timeline as a table view object within the View Controller, which didn't work. I'm guessing that is not permitted within TWTRTimelineViewController.

Comment: Please let us know what you've tried, an what is actually going wrong. Is there an error? Is there no error? What's happening?

Comment: I tried implementing the Twitter timeline as a table view object within the View Controller, which didn't work. I'm guessing that is not permitted within TWTRTimelineViewController.

Comment: In what way did it not work? The more specific you are, the better the answers will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say we have a regular viewcontroller which contains both the tweet section and the other stuff, now you can make your UI but instead of the timeline part you add an UIContainerView (drag it in in storyboard) and make the embedded viewcontroller the TWTRTimelineViewController.

This way you can use the standard viewcontroller and still have it embedded somewhere.

I hope I understood your problem well.